# Unable to add Font-Awesome icon to button via setState() in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

In my class, I am setting a button text as a state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    buttonText: 'LOGIN',
    };
}
```

The button markup is as follows:

```
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary w-100 my-2">{this.state.buttonText}</button>
```

I am trying to dynamically change the text to a FA icon by altering the value in `buttonText` via a function:

```
onSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({
   buttonText: '<i className="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true" />',
});
axios.post('/api/authentication/login', { username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password })
    .then((response) => {
        this.props.onLogin(response.data);
        this.props.toggle();
     });
}
```

This works, as in the button re-renders with the new text; however, instead of the FA icon, it renders with the markup, i.e. `<i className="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true" />` shows up as a raw text in the button's caption. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can also check the `react-async-button` component (https://github.com/selvagsz/react-async-button) to stay DRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution alters the DOM dynamically by entering html. This can be achieved with [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html) but i wouldn't recommend it when a perfectly viable solution is available:

I propose that you create an  element and toggle whether this renders via a Boolean property in your state. For example `{loading:false}`

```
<i className="..." style={this.state.loading ? {display:'inline'} : {display:'none'}} />
```

Then have your onSubmit method toggle the `loading` properly in your state

Answer (score 0):

Just remove single quote from `'<i className="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true" />'`

```
onSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({
   buttonText: <i className="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true" />,
});
axios.post('/api/authentication/login', { username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password })
    .then((response) => {
        this.props.onLogin(response.data);
        this.props.toggle();
     });
}
```